# SqLServer - Subquery return same value instead null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve some values using a subquery but if i use operator "IN", the results displays the same values for "StartDate" and only 1 register has values, the others are empty.

If i change the operator "IN"  for "=", i got an error message because subquery return multiple values.

Example:

Wrong return:

```
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=2768   2014-04-02 11:22:20.637
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=2917   2014-04-02 11:22:20.637
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=3130   2014-04-02 11:22:20.637
```

Correct returns:

```
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=2768   null
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=2917   null
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=3130   2014-04-02 11:22:20.637
```

or

```
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=2766   2014-04-12 19:31:49.867
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=2918   null
MyThread     clientId=300&campId=3130   2014-04-02 11:22:20.637
```

How can i fix my query to return the correct value for each row?

```
SELECT l.ThreadName,
   l.Message,
(SELECT StartDate
FROM DevBase.dbo.CutStatusTask csut
WHERE CampaignId IN
   (SELECT REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(ltmp.Message,'&','.'),1), 'campId=', '')
    FROM notifier.Log ltmp
    WHERE ltmp.Type = '[RECURRING_START]'
      AND l.Type = '[RECURRING_START]')
 AND csut.NewStatus = 'TESTING') AS startdate
FROM notifier.log l
WHERE l.Type LIKE '%RECURRING_START%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a simple `left join`. Why are you using a subquery?

Comment: I'm using a subquery because i need to do "REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(ltmp.Message,'&','.'),1), 'campId=', '')" .. and i don't know how to it outside a subquery. Can i do it in a Where clause? And i'll use this sql in an UNION ALL with other sqls

Comment: Nice!!! And now my query is very simple to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use a leading wildcard in your WHERE clause?  Not recommended as you will have to do a full table scan and I'm guessing your log table will be (or get) quite large...

Comment: It's not working like i was thinking hehe...i need subquery because StartDate value is in another table and DateEnd is in table Log. I need to do something like 'regex' to extract CampaignId and search for startdate..if i do a left join, i'll look only for START/END registers and i need to look for both in my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit difficult to see the table relationships from your example, but something like this?

```
SELECT l.ThreadName,
   l.Message,
   csut.StartDate

FROM notifier.log l
INNER JOIN DevBase.dbo.CutStatusTask csut ON csut.CampaignId = l.CampaignId 

WHERE csut.CampaignId = REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(l.Message,'&','.'),1), 'campId=', '')
AND (l.Type LIKE '%RECURRING_START%'
     OR
     l.Type LIKE '%RECURRING_END%')
```

Comment: It's work if i could search only for 'Recurring Start' or 'Recurring End. I need to look for both registers together :(

Comment: Just amended the AND condition. If this isn't right, please can you add some sample data from your two tables into the question to demonstrate your example. It will really help

Answer (score 0):

The following query would search for both Start Date and End Date. The `INNER JOIN` condition contains conditions for `RECURRING_START` and `RECURRING_END`, using OR.

```
SELECT 
  l.ThreadName,
  L.MESSAGE,
  CSUT.STARTDATE,
  CSUT.ENDDATE
FROM NOTIFIER.LOG L
INNER JOIN DEVBASE.DBO.CUTSTATUSTASK CSUT
ON 
(L.TYPE LIKE '%RECURRING_START%' AND CSUT.CAMPAIGNID = REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(L.MESSAGE,'&','.'),1), 'campId=', ''))
OR
(L.TYPE LIKE '%RECURRING_END%' AND CSUT.CAMPAIGNID = REPLACE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(L.MESSAGE,'&','.'),1), 'campId=', ''));
```